# Make UIStackView hug its content

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, uistackview

I'm trying to implement a basic layout using a main horizontal `UIStackView`, with 2 children vertical `UIStackViews`.

[image]

Here is what I want:

- the red view has 2 constraints: width = height = 50
- the left vertical stackview(with the green label) should be as wide as its largest child, and should center all children horizontally.
- the right vertical stackview(with the yellow label) should take up all available space.

Setting the alignment of the left vertical stack to `fill` expands the yellow label but do makes the red and green views have the same width. Changing the alignment to `center` make the left stack not hug it's children (just like in the image).

[image]

Any ideas how this should be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that a vertical `UIStackView` with `Alignment: Center` has no intrinsic width.

To get the layout you want, you'll need to embed the RedView in either a clear `UIView` or another stack view, with its alignment set to Center.

Here's the approach with a stack view, as we need a couple fewer constraints than with a "container" view:

[image]

Since the RedView has width and height constraints, it will always be `50 x 50`.

The "outer" stack view - `HorizontalStack` - is constrained to all four sides, with 8-pts "padding". Its properties are:

```
Axis: Horizontal
Alignment: Center
Distribution: Fill
Spacing: 0
```

The `LeftVerticalStack` properties are:

```
Axis: Vertical
Alignment: Fill
Distribution: Fill
Spacing: 0
```

And the `RedContainerStack` properties are:

```
Axis: Vertical
Alignment: Center
Distribution: Fill
Spacing: 0
```

One last necessary setting - the Green Label needs to hug its content and resist compression:

[image]

The result (with a few different strings in the labels):

[image]

Here's the source for `MyCollCell.xib`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<document type="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder3.CocoaTouch.XIB" version="3.0" toolsVersion="16096" targetRuntime="iOS.CocoaTouch" propertyAccessControl="none" useAutolayout="YES" useTraitCollections="YES" useSafeAreas="YES" colorMatched="YES">
    <device id="retina6_1" orientation="portrait" appearance="light"/>
    <dependencies>
        <plugIn identifier="com.apple.InterfaceBuilder.IBCocoaTouchPlugin" version="16087"/>
        <capability name="collection view cell content view" minToolsVersion="11.0"/>
        <capability name="documents saved in the Xcode 8 format" minToolsVersion="8.0"/>
    </dependencies>
    <objects>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFilesOwner" id="-1" userLabel="File's Owner"/>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="-2" customClass="UIResponder"/>
        <collectionViewCell opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" reuseIdentifier="Cell" id="p9p-j5-QAK" customClass="MyCollCell" customModule="TableAdd" customModuleProvider="target">
            <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="309" height="122"/>
            <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask" flexibleMaxX="YES" flexibleMaxY="YES"/>
            <collectionViewCellContentView key="contentView" opaque="NO" clipsSubviews="YES" multipleTouchEnabled="YES" contentMode="center" insetsLayoutMarginsFromSafeArea="NO" id="7Um-4C-5Kc">
                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="309" height="122"/>
                <autoresizingMask key="autoresizingMask"/>
                <subviews>
                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" alignment="center" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="Ezy-2A-s1y" userLabel="HorizontalStack">
                        <rect key="frame" x="8" y="8" width="293" height="106"/>
                        <subviews>
                            <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="63E-WY-6Uf" userLabel="LeftVerticalStack">
                                <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="18" width="92.5" height="70.5"/>
                                <subviews>
                                    <stackView opaque="NO" contentMode="scaleToFill" axis="vertical" alignment="center" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="HgJ-l5-geV" userLabel="RedContainerStack">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="0.0" width="92.5" height="50"/>
                                        <subviews>
                                            <view contentMode="scaleToFill" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="od9-kp-hKh" userLabel="RedView">
                                                <rect key="frame" x="21.5" y="0.0" width="50" height="50"/>
                                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.90437477830000002" green="0.1580897272" blue="0.20071530339999999" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                                <constraints>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="height" constant="50" id="R5P-yj-c9R"/>
                                                    <constraint firstAttribute="width" constant="50" id="zOV-Xo-aVe"/>
                                                </constraints>
                                            </view>
                                        </subviews>
                                    </stackView>
                                    <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="1000" verticalHuggingPriority="251" horizontalCompressionResistancePriority="1000" text="Green Label" textAlignment="center" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="xzN-ta-GJB">
                                        <rect key="frame" x="0.0" y="50" width="92.5" height="20.5"/>
                                        <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.1673075259" green="0.65853333469999997" blue="0.26840484139999998" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                        <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                        <nil key="textColor"/>
                                        <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                                    </label>
                                </subviews>
                            </stackView>
                            <label opaque="NO" userInteractionEnabled="NO" contentMode="left" horizontalHuggingPriority="251" verticalHuggingPriority="251" text="Yellow Label" textAlignment="natural" lineBreakMode="tailTruncation" baselineAdjustment="alignBaselines" adjustsFontSizeToFit="NO" translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints="NO" id="ReT-76-3Fl">
                                <rect key="frame" x="92.5" y="43" width="200.5" height="20.5"/>
                                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.99657744169999996" green="0.79237681630000001" blue="0.0001898294868" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                                <fontDescription key="fontDescription" type="system" pointSize="17"/>
                                <nil key="textColor"/>
                                <nil key="highlightedColor"/>
                            </label>
                        </subviews>
                    </stackView>
                </subviews>
                <color key="backgroundColor" red="0.46202266219999999" green="0.83828371759999998" blue="1" alpha="1" colorSpace="custom" customColorSpace="sRGB"/>
                <constraints>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="trailing" secondItem="Ezy-2A-s1y" secondAttribute="trailing" constant="8" id="FlO-FQ-5GG"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="Ezy-2A-s1y" firstAttribute="top" secondItem="7Um-4C-5Kc" secondAttribute="top" constant="8" id="ct6-Mf-RVp"/>
                    <constraint firstAttribute="bottom" secondItem="Ezy-2A-s1y" secondAttribute="bottom" constant="8" id="dsT-ps-AIz"/>
                    <constraint firstItem="Ezy-2A-s1y" firstAttribute="leading" secondItem="7Um-4C-5Kc" secondAttribute="leading" constant="8" id="wAj-T5-Vzs"/>
                </constraints>
            </collectionViewCellContentView>
            <size key="customSize" width="309" height="122"/>
            <connections>
                <outlet property="greenLabel" destination="xzN-ta-GJB" id="1Tu-hu-JOb"/>
                <outlet property="yellowLabel" destination="ReT-76-3Fl" id="zTt-ML-CsA"/>
            </connections>
            <point key="canvasLocation" x="165.94202898550725" y="145.98214285714286"/>
        </collectionViewCell>
    </objects>
</document>
```

And here is example code I used to produce the output shown above:

```
import UIKit

private let reuseIdentifier = "Cell"

// cell sizing extension and systemLayoutSizeFitting implementation
// is not mine, but can be found here:
// https://www.robertpieta.com/autosizing-full-width-cells/
extension UICollectionView {
    var widestCellWidth: CGFloat {
        let insets = contentInset.left + contentInset.right
        return bounds.width - insets
    }
}

class MyCollCell: UICollectionViewCell {
    
    @IBOutlet var greenLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var yellowLabel: UILabel!

    override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(
        _ targetSize: CGSize,
        withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority,
        verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
        
        // Replace the height in the target size to
        // allow the cell to flexibly compute its height
        var targetSize = targetSize
        targetSize.height = CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude
        
        // The .required horizontal fitting priority means
        // the desired cell width (targetSize.width) will be
        // preserved. However, the vertical fitting priority is
        // .fittingSizeLevel meaning the cell will find the
        // height that best fits the content
        let size = super.systemLayoutSizeFitting(
            targetSize,
            withHorizontalFittingPriority: .required,
            verticalFittingPriority: .fittingSizeLevel
        )
        
        return size
    }

}

class MyCollectionViewController: UICollectionViewController {

    let myData: [[String]] = [
        ["Green Label", "Yellow Label"],
        ["G", "Yellow Label"],
        ["Longer Green Label", "Yellow Label"],
        ["Green Label", "Yellow Label with too much text to fit here."],
        ["Green Label", "Yellow Label with .numberOfLines set to 0 will wrap when there's too much text."],
    ]
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Register cell classes
        self.collectionView.register(UINib(nibName: "MyCollCell", bundle: nil), forCellWithReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)

        let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout
        if let flowLayout = layout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
            flowLayout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(
                width: collectionView.widestCellWidth,
                // Make the height a reasonable estimate to
                // ensure the scroll bar remains smooth
                height: 100
            )
        }

    }

    // MARK: UICollectionViewDataSource

    override func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return myData.count
    }
    override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! MyCollCell
    
        cell.greenLabel.text = myData[indexPath.row][0]
        cell.yellowLabel.text = myData[indexPath.row][1]
        
        cell.yellowLabel.numberOfLines = indexPath.item == 4 ? 0 : 1

        return cell
    }

}
```

Comment: Awesomely detailed. It worked wonderfully. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 0):

With reference to the photo I uploaded below, I placed the **left** **vertical stack view** in a **UIView** (Purple) and then embedded them in a **horizontal stack view** with the **yellow label**. I set the distribution to be **equal spacing** with a **spacing of 0** so that there would be no spacing.

I set the **constraints** for all sides of the **left vertical stack view** to be 0 (so that the left vertical stack view would take the whole purple UIView). Set the **alignment** to **center** also so that the child views are in the center horizontally.

Inside the **left vertical stack view**, I added a **constraint of 0** for the **trailing, leading and bottom** so that the left stack view is as "wide" as the largest children (which is the green label). I changed the label text to be center so that the text is at the center.

Hope this answers your question!

[Check the image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/divkO.png)

Comment: In your posted image the greenLabel is wider than it's intrinsic content size. I don't want that.